# how does this code not cause a buffer overflow?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    char s[10];

    while (fscanf(stdin, "%10s", s) != 1) {
    }

    printf("%s", s);
}
```

However the code runs perfectly fine.

How is this?

The buffer `s` is size 10 but if i input a string such as `helloworld` which is 10 characters long the `printf` statement will print `helloworld`. How is this possible? I thought that it would print `helloworl` which i thought would look like this:

```
index 0: h
index 1: e
index 2: l
index 3: l
index 4: o
index 5: w
index 6: o
index 7: r
index 8: l
index 9: \0
```

why does this still work for me? and print `helloworld`? it seems like the null terminator is not even there. what is going on?

Comment: It would have printed `helloworl` if you had made it `"%9s"` instead. Right now you have undefined behavior and _anything_ can happen - including appearing to work fine.

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior since `%10s` will read 10 characters and then put the null terminator after them. The null terminator is outside the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line: `char s[10];`
You asked for, and were allocated, 10 bytes in the array `s`.

All other data is beyond your control, and could have any value at all.
It could be used by device-drivers, or other programs, or even not be valid memory at all.

Then using `fscanf` you filled in **11** bytes with values `HelloWorld` and a `\0` Terminator.

This is where the trouble starts.  Your code filled in byte #11, which you have not explicitly reserved for your use.

`printf` will print a string until it finds a `\0` terminator.
You do not have a guarantee of a terminator, so ***anything*** could happen.

Lucky for you, it seems that extra byte is available, and has not been overwritten by any other task/process/thread/device.  There happens to be a `\0` at the end of the text, and it behaves normally.  But that is *undefined behavior*, and anything could very well have happened.

It would be totally legit if your computer had printed:

```
HelloWorldPrepareForGozerTheGozerian
```

Comment: `fscanf()` writes the null terminator in the next byte. It doesn't know that the array was declared `[10]` in the next byte, you're required to allocate enough for the word and the terminator.

Comment: Don't say "NULL terminator". That confuses the null byte with the `NULL` pointer.